# iframe appends to makes a copy

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got this jQuery code but when I try to execute it, it makes a copy of `blok2` when it returns to its formal state. Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Whenever I click on my blok it expands and shows to video like it's supposed to. But when i click to scale it down it makes a copy of the iframe and it wont go to hide. I tried some solutions but i don't  know how to unhide the iframe and that it wont go dubble.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blok2").click(function() {
    $(".codeacademy").toggle();
  });
  $(".blok2").click(function() {
    $("<iframe />", {
      src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/07Q6aUPfqkM"
    }).appendTo(".blok2");
  });
});
```

```css
.rij1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.rij2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.blok1 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.blok2 {
  background-color: palevioletred;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.blok3 {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.blok4 {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
img.codeacademy {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  content: url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/logo_blue_dark.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='rij1'>
  <div class='blok1'></div>
  <div class='blok2'>
    <img class="codeacademy">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='rij2'>
  <div class='blok3'></div>
  <div class='blok4'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the fact that you have two click event handlers attached to the `blok2` element - they both execute on each click; they don't toggle on successive clicks as you seem to be expecting.

To fix this you can have a single click event handler which checks if there is an `iframe` within the `blok2` element already. If there is, it removes it and shows the codecademy image. If not, it creates the iframe and hides the image. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blok2").click(function() {
    var $iframe = $(this).find('iframe');
    if ($iframe.length) {
      $(".codeacademy").show();
      $iframe.remove();
    } else {
      $(".codeacademy").hide();
      $("<iframe />", {
        src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/07Q6aUPfqkM"
      }).appendTo(".blok2");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rij1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.rij2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.blok1 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.blok2 {
  background-color: palevioletred;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.blok3 {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.blok4 {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
img.codeacademy {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  content: url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/logo_blue_dark.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='rij1'>
  <div class='blok1'></div>
  <div class='blok2'>
    <img class="codeacademy">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='rij2'>
  <div class='blok3'></div>
  <div class='blok4'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.